# Posting model from MVC to action using jquery post

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to post my model to an MVC Action, using jquery post. In MVC, I'm doing the following to serialise my model to JSON:

**MVC:**

```
<div class="myModel" hidden="true">@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(".confirm_yes").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get credit card session id
    var sessionid = $(this).parent().find(".payu_creditcard_sessionid").text();

    var myModel = $(".myModel").text();
    $.post("/payuwalletlink/removecreditcard", { model: myModel }, function (data) {

        //do whatever with the returned view.

    });
});
```

**Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RemoveCreditCard(CreditCardModel model)
{

    return View("PayUwallet");
}
```

But I get the following error from my browser:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Very strange way to pass data to page and then send back the untouched string which would still be escaped

Comment: as was mentioned what you are passing in your code is the model that was passed to the view.  If you want to pass the updated model of the current view you need to generate an array in jquery that matches your model structure and pass that.  MVC will map it to your model on the controller side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to be doing makes no sense. Why would you pass a model to a view and then post it completely unchanged?. However, the way to do this if needed, is to convert the model to a javascript object and post it back

```
var myModel = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))');

$(".confirm_yes").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Get credit card session id
  var sessionid = $(this).parent().find(".payu_creditcard_sessionid").text();     
  $.post('@Url.Action("removecreditcard", "payuwalletlink")', myModel , function (data) {
    ....
  });
});
```

Not sure what `var sessionid = ..` is for (you don't seem to use it).

I suspect what your trying to is delete an object on the post method, in which case, just pass back the `ID` of the object.

Comment: This is exactly what I told the developer who was writting the backend code, he asked for me to pass the entire model back, with the selected credit card entry to remove. I told him this is bad practice, and that he only needs me to pass the id (sessionid,thats what the property is called). I've now escalated this to senior developers who agreed that what he wanted was wrong. Your answer basically sums up what I wanted to do, so I'll accept this answer. Thank you.

Comment: You would certainly get much better performance using `$.post('@Url.Action("removecreditcard", "payuwalletlink")', { id: sessionid }, function (data) { ..`  and post back to `public ActionResult RemoveCreditCard(int id) { ..`

Comment: is it a good approach to store model in a hidden view. isnt there a better way to do this?

Comment: @batmaci Sorry, not sure what do you mean? What OP was doing makes no sense and is not a good approach, but if you want to send the whole model back to the controller, then you have to include it in the view. But as I noted, you should be sending back just the `id` of the model, not the model, and if you need the model in the controller, then call the database to get it again based on the `id`

Comment: @StephenMuecke what if my controller gets parameter as model returns model like        Return View("~/Views/Products.cshtml", ProductModel)

am I able to get like this?  $.post('Url.Action("Product", "Filter")', JSON.stringify({ Model }) , function (data) {

Comment: @batmaci, No - it needs to be as per my answer. But its awful practice to do that as I have previously noted.